# Angular Material Errors

Tags: angular

Good Morning, i have this error any help please :

```
ERROR in Error:
Metadata version mismatch for module
/home/sindibadpc1/Documents/WebstormProjects/landing/node_modules/@angular/material/core/typings/index.d.ts, found version 4, expected 3, resolving symbol MaterialModule in
/home/sindibadpc1/Documents/WebstormProjects/landing/src/app/material.module.ts,
resolving symbol MaterialModule in/home/sindibadpc1/Documents/WebstormProjects/landing/src/app/material.module.ts
```

Comment: Can you provide your package.json?

Answer (score -2):

Make sure that all your dependencies are up to date.

Your dependencies should look something like this:

```
"dependencies": {
 "@angular/material": "^5.0.0-rc1",
 "@angular/cdk": "^5.0.0-rc1",
 "@angular/animations": "^5.0.0",
 "@angular/common": "^5.0.0",
 "@angular/compiler": "^5.0.0",
 "@angular/core": "^5.0.0",
 "@angular/forms": "^5.0.0",
 "@angular/http": "^5.0.0",
 "@angular/platform-browser": "^5.0.0",
 "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.0.0",
 "@angular/router": "^5.0.0",
 "rxjs": "^5.5.2"
}
```

https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/8229

Comment: Thank you ,but i would like to use Angular Material in an Angular4 project?